# Enable datadog tracing for apache wsgi flask app

Tags: python, docker, mod-wsgi, wsgi, datadog

I have python flask docker app running on apache server with mod_wsgi. I wanted to datadog tracing to the app but I am confused where on entrypoint I should add ddtrace-run command. The only thing we do on entrypoint is "/run-apache.sh".

I tried ["ddtrace-run", "sh", "/run-apache.sh"] but it didn't work.

My run-apache.sh script has

```
exec /usr/sbin/apachectl -DFOREGROUND
```

Blockquote

Can you help me understand how we can run the app with ddtrace here.